# Which summoner spells are locked by Skarner's ultimate?

Tags: league-of-legends

Skarner's ultimate prevents auto-attacks, casting E, and flash, but permits casting Q, W, and Exhaust.

So some summoner spells are permitted during Skarner's ult, and others are forbidden. Which are permitted, and which are locked?

Comment: Can you stop channeling Skarner's ult or deactivate it in any way?

Comment: @Sadly Skarner cannot turn off his ultimate, and CC doesn't stop it either. The victim can remove it with QSS or Oranges, the opposing team can remove it by killing Skarner.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Flash and teleport are forbidden (for evident reasons), all the others (including ghost) are allowed.

Basically, you can't cast anything teleporting you nor trigger an action that uses your tail (as it is used by ulti), these actions include auto-attacks and E.